# How to select specific countries to make a choropleth map

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth, choroplethr

I'm trying to make a choropleth map of some specific countries. I have the data with values for the choropleth map, and the other countries that I don't have data will be plotted in grey.

So here is my code until now:

```
data_iso = data.frame(region=c("Argentina", "Brazil",   "Chile", "Colombia", "Costa Rica", "Mexico", "Panama", "Peru",  "El Salvador"),
                      ratemort = c(25.510391, 73.875825,20.297896,  73.557939  ,23.266236,  42.190321,  48.069608,  9.971303 ,109.941822))

library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)
library(maptools)

mapa <- borders("world", regions = c("Brazil", "Uruguay", "Argentina", "French Guiana", "Suriname", "Colombia", "Venezuela",
                                     "Bolivia", "Ecuador", "Chile", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Guyana", "Panama", "Costa Rica", 
                                     "Nicaragua", "Honduras", "El Salvador", "Belize", "Guatemala", "Mexico", "Trinidad and Tobago",
                                     "Caribe", "Puerto Rico", "Dominican Republic", "Haiti", "Jamaica", "Cuba", "Bahamas", "Antiles",
                                     "Dominica", "Saba"), 
                fill = "grey70", colour = "black")
ggplot() + mapa + theme_bw() + xlab("Longitude (decimals)") + ylab("Latitude (decimals)") + 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80"), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

Then, I'd like to add the values of `data_iso$ratemort` in the their respective countries.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what your question is. But since you used the `choroplethr` tag I will explain how to make the map using the `choroplethr` package:

```
data_iso = data.frame(region=c("argentina", "brazil",   "chile", "colombia", "costa rica", "mexico", "panama", "peru",  "el salvador"),
                      value = c(25.510391, 73.875825,20.297896,  73.557939  ,23.266236,  42.190321,  48.069608,  9.971303 ,109.941822))

country_choropleth(data_iso, zoom=data_iso$region)
```

[image]

The key modification is this. The function `?country_choropleth`, like all functions in the `choroplethr` suite of packages, requires your dataframe to have one column named `region` and one column named `value`. Also, all regions in `choroplethr` generally use lowercase. See `?country_choroplethr` for details on naming conventions.

Your map has no color. I am not sure if that is the error that you want help with.

By default `choroplethr` uses Black to convey NA values. Here I set the zoom to be only countries that have data. I do not know if all the counties in your zoom list are present in the map, if they are spelled in the same way they appear in the map, and so on. See the `zoom` parameter in `?country_choropleth` for details. Getting the naming right is normally the hardest part of mapping in R (including the choroplethr package).

Comment: Is it possible to add countries with NA values and don't show NA in the legend and show the scale bar?

Comment: in ggplot, you can use something like this for NA values:         scale_fill_continuous(low = "lightblue", high = "darkblue",
                              guide = "colorbar", na.value = "grey")

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ggplot, you need to add your dataframe to `ggplot` and add `fill` in `aes` with your column so that the map fills the colors based on the values of the ratemort.

Try something like this:

```
ggplot(data = data_iso, aes(fill = ratemort)) + mapa + theme_bw() +  
 xlab("Longitude (decimals)") + ylab("Latitude (decimals)") +  
 theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major =  
 element_line(colour = "grey80"), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```